# highslide not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highslide

I have been bending over backwards trying to get this to work. The highslide gallery is supposed to expand when you click the open gallery link. The loader gif just keeps spinning. I've made sure everything is is in it's proper place on the server, all the extentions are .jpg and not.JPG, firebug shows nothing.

Am I misiing something?

SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="highslide/highslide-with-gallery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="highslide/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="highslide/highslide.css" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="highslide/highslide-ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

BODY

```
<div class="highslide-gallery">
    <a id="gallery-opener" href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('thumb1').onclick()">
        Open gallery
    </a>

    <div class="hidden-container">
    <a id="thumb1" href="http://www.flyfishinggreyriver.comhighslide/images/large/Irisflower2.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/Irisflower2.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/Monstertree.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/Monstertree.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/Lodge-riverfromair.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/Lodge-riverfromair.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/DCP_1063.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/DCP_1063.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/Margie-Karen-hike.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/Margie-Karen-hike.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/DCP_0912.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/DCP_0912.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/StickBird2.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/StickBird2.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/ForksoverviewII.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/ForksoverviewII.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/Lodgefromnearbyhill2.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/Lodgefromnearbyhill2.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/DCP_1054.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/DCP_1054.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/DCP_2289.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/DCP_2289.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/RedFoxatPeterStrides.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/RedFoxatPeterStrides.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/SBFalls-riverfromair.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/SBFalls-riverfromair.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/HikingoverviewForksLodge.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/HikingoverviewForksLodge.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/DCP_1064.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/DCP_1064.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/CampBear.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/CampBear.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/SBbelowLodgefromnearbyhill.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/SBbelowLodgefromnearbyhill.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/RiverbelowSBLodge.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/RiverbelowSBLodge.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/SBLodgefromnearbyhill2.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/SBLodgefromnearbyhill2.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/WildRoses.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/WildRoses.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/DCP_1487.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/DCP_1487.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/Lunchtimeinthefall.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/Lunchtimeinthefall.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/SBLodgefromnearbyhill3.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/SBLodgefromnearbyhill3.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/pitcherplant.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/pitcherplant.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/Henr-NfIsl.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/Henr-NfIsl.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/LadysSlipper2.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/LadysSlipper2.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/DCP_2267.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/DCP_2267.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/Snoop.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/Snoop.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/CroppedPhoto.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/CroppedPhoto.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/LiftingoffatTheForksLodge.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/LiftingoffatTheForksLodge.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/FORKSOVERVIEW.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/FORKSOVERVIEW.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/MyPictures0259.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/MyPictures0259.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/GreyRiverLodge_GSL9118.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/GreyRiverLodge_GSL9118.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/MyPictures0256.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/MyPictures0256.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/Henry-Emilys.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/Henry-Emilys.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/MyPictures0001.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/MyPictures0001.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/Hosp-LipfromClf.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/Hosp-LipfromClf.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/Owlintree2.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/Owlintree2.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/Wedding_GSL8893.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/Wedding_GSL8893.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="highslide/images/large/g.r.fromair2.jpg" class="highslide" 
            title="" 
            onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
        <img src="highslide/images/thumbs/g.r.fromair2.jpg"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'ver never fiddleed around over there. How does it work?

Comment: Please use this link 
http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Is Your HTML file in the same folder as the highslide folder? If not try to put it there and than relink the javascript and css.